# Proving equivalence of first and second quantisation (Pathria's way)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, many-body, second-quantization

I'm trying to solve problem 11.1 form [Pathria R. K. & Beale P. D. - Statistical mechanics book](https://archive.org/details/PathriaR.K.BealeP.D.StatisticalMechanics/page/n401) (the hyperlink will get you straight to the page of the problem). The point (b) is to show the equivalence of the two equations
\begin{equation}
\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\sum_{i =1}^N\nabla^2_i + \sum_{i<j} U_{ij}\right)\Phi_{NE}(\vec{r}_1,\dots, \vec{r}_N) = E\Phi_{NE}(\vec{r}_1,\dots, \vec{r}_N),
\end{equation}
where all the quantities are defined in [previous pages](https://archive.org/details/PathriaR.K.BealeP.D.StatisticalMechanics/page/n357), and the equation
\begin{equation}
\frac1{\sqrt{N!}}\langle0| \hat{\Psi}(\vec{r}_1)\cdots\hat{\Psi}(\vec{r}_N)\hat{H}|\Phi_{NE}\rangle = E\Phi_{NE}(\vec{r}_1,\dots, \vec{r}_N),
\end{equation}
by making use of the commutation relation
\begin{equation}
 [\hat{\Psi}(\vec{r}_j), \hat{H}] = \left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2_j + \int\mathrm{d}\vec{r}\hat{\Psi}^\dagger(\vec{r})U(\vec{r}, \vec{r}_j)\hat{\Psi}(\vec{r})\right)\hat{\Psi}(\vec{r}_j).
\end{equation}
I was able to carry out the kinetic term $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\sum_{i =1}^N\nabla^2_i$, but I can't figure out how to leave only the term $U_{ij}$ (which I presume being $U(r_i, r_j)$) because I get some other terms of the form $\int\mathrm{d}\vec{r}\hat{\Psi}^\dagger(\vec{r})U(\vec{r}, \vec{r}_j)\hat{\Psi}(\vec{r})$, which are non vanishing. Some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider one-particle operators of the form
$$
\hat{A} = \int d\vec{r}\ \hat{\Psi}^\dagger(\vec{r}) a(\vec{r}) \hat{\Psi}(\vec{r}).
$$
Using commutation relations and vacuum vector properties it is straightforward to obtain following property of this operators
$$
\left<0\right|\hat{\Psi}(\vec{r}_1)\cdots\hat{\Psi}(\vec{r}_{j-1})\hat{A} = \sum_{i=1}^{j-1} a(\vec{r}_i) \left<0\right|\hat{\Psi}(\vec{r}_1)\cdots\hat{\Psi}(\vec{r}_{j-1}).\qquad (*)
$$
If we take $a(\vec{r}) = U(\vec{r},\vec{r}_j)$, then it is not difficult to get from $(*)$ to the equality
$$
\left<0\right|\hat{\Psi}(\vec{r}_1)\cdots\hat{\Psi}(\vec{r}_{j-1})\int d\vec{r}\ \hat{\Psi}^\dagger(\vec{r})U(\vec{r},\vec{r}_j)\hat{\Psi}(\vec{r})\hat{\Psi}(\vec{r}_j) \cdots\hat{\Psi}(\vec{r}_N)\left|\Phi_{NE}\right>\ =
$$
$$
=\ \sum_{i=1}^{j-1} U(\vec{r}_i,\vec{r}_j) \left<0\right|\hat{\Psi}(\vec{r}_1)\cdots\hat{\Psi}(\vec{r}_N)\left|\Phi_{NE}\right>
$$
Now it is easy to finish the solution.